# Comparing a javascript variable with a part of a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to compare a `var foo = 'whatever'` with THIS:

```
<ul id="nav_main"><li><a href="index.php?pag=THIS">link</a></li></ul>
```

And then, put `class="current"` inside the matched `<li>`.

Comment: I am asking because i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var foo = 'whatever';
$("#nav_main li a").filter(function(index){
    return foo === this.href.match(/pag=(.*)/)[1];
}).parent().addClass("current");
```

Would that work?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rREry/1

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = 'THIS';
$('a[href*="'+foo+'"]', '#nav_main').closest('li').addClass('current');
```

This searches for `<a>` tags that have an `href` attribute containing the string, and adds the class to their containing `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#nav_main li').each(function() {  // loop through each <li>
    if ($(this).find('a').attr('href') == foo) {   // check against your var (not sure what exactly you wanted to check)
        $(this).addClass('current');       // add the "current" class if it matches
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (foo == "<ul id="nav_main"><li><a href="index.php?pag=THIS">link</a></li></ul>"){
  foo.addClass("current")
}
```