# Comparing a javascript variable with a part of a href for 2 level navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

[Comparing a javascript variable with a part of a href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915916/comparing-a-javascript-variable-with-a-part-of-a-href)

the link above is the similar question to my current one it works perfectly for one level navigation bar but i have 2 level of navigation bar that is a drop down bar and i want to achieve the same result

```
<ul id="nav_main"> 
    <li><a href="index.php?pag=THIS">link</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?pag=secondthis">link</a></li>
    </ul></li>
</ul>
```

it has to match the herf tag to the a java script variable and put current class for both the child li and the parent li

Comment: Did you at least try to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var foo = 'whatever';
$("#nav_main li a").filter(function(index){
    return foo === this.href.match(/pag=(.*)/)[1];
}).parents('li').addClass("current");
```

Changed `.parent()` to `.parents('li')` to select all parent `li`s and add the class to them.

Comment: hi thanks a lot ya it works with this code thanks a lot there is only one small change instead of $("#nav_main li a") u should use $("#nav_main li ul li a")thanks great help